# voice recording on iPhone and sending the data to database for further process

Tags: database, swift, voice-recognition, voice, voice-recording

I have this project that I need to record human voice on my IOS Swift app and then send it to database for further process using Matlab for extracting features from the recorded voice . But I have no idea what kind of database should I use and where to start for sending the voice to database . I will highly appreciate if you have any recommendation or solution . 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Start with google query

Comment: Thanks @NikolayShmyrev